# How to deal with data that divided into periods

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-mining

I am trying to build ml model, and have data is divided into periods(e.g. months). Dataset has over 200 features!
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shTNG.png)

Your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply treat `month` as a categorical feature? That is, don't treat the number as numeric; instead of `1`, ..., `12`, the values of `month` might as well be `January`, ..., `December`.

Comment: Yes, thanks for advice, i can but i don't understand another thing. As you can see I have an object with 6 periods (6 rows) and for this there is 1 label. I don't understand how to build a model in this case. Before I worked with data 1 label treats to 1 row in data.